What exactly is Szekeres saying?
I'm reading a book by Szekeres P (2004) A modern course in Mathematical Physics and it has an excerpt here that goes:

We have good reason to believe that on time scales less than the Planck time [...] the continuum fabric of space-time is probably invalid and a quantum theory of gravity becomes operative. It is highly likely that differential equations have little or no physical relevance below or at the Planck scale.

Ok, sure pal. But like, what does that even mean? Differential equations don't have physical relevance below or at the Planck scale? Is this basically a way of saying the geometry is expected to become non commutative just at/below the Planck scale so like $[x^μ,x^v] = iθ^{μv}$ ? What does he mean?

Szekeres surely believed that General Relativity needs to be superseded by a Quantum Gravity Theory at the Planck energetic scale and higher. Assuming his point of view is "a discrete time and space", differential equations are trivially irrelevant. Instead, you have to define things with finite differences. Non-commutative geometry has little to do with that. Of course, this is his point of view, and different models of Quantum Gravity will not agree on the "discreteness of space".

Ty Roux. I understood this way much better than whatever tf the answer given below was trying to say (which I've dismissed as genuinely difficult to understand) and will be reading more into this.

It means that "highly likely" these statements have "little or no physical relevance".

"good reason to believe": physics is not religion
"time scales less than the Planck time": cannot exist because they would not be measurable.
"fabric of space-time": space-time is a manifold and not matter
"probably invalid": with what 3 sigma, please?

The existence of the Planck scale is a property of matter, not of spacetime. Measurements are made on matter using matter. So one can expect the values of measured physical quantities to have a Planck limit. Spacetime on the other hand is immaterial and continues as a manifold.
